# Different strict mode value for different templates for Qute in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I use Quarkus which uses Qute as a template engine.

Is it possible to have strict mode `true` for some template(s) and strict-mode `false` for some other(s)?

```
  @Location("report1-strict.html")
  Template templateStrict;

  @Location("report2-nonstrict.html")
  Template templateNonStrict;
```

I've checked Qute configuration and it looks like strict mode can be set only for an `Engine` and not for a `Template` or as some parameter of a `render(...)` methods.

Then maybe it's possible to have 2 engines in Quarkus app?
Do I need to create another Qute `Engine` instance manuyally?

The best would be to set up a strict mode on template rendering manually but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have strict mode true for some template(s) and strict-mode false for some other(s)?

No, this is not possible. Strict rendering can be configured per an `Engine` instance.

> Then maybe it's possible to have 2 engines in Quarkus app? Do I need to create another Qute Engine instance manuyally?

You can have many `Engine` instances but only the instance preconfigured by Quarkus is fully integrated, i.e. you would have to mimic the logic from the [EngineProducer](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/qute/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/qute/runtime/EngineProducer.java).